# ng-includeディレクティブのautoscroll属性について

Tags: angularjs

ng-includeディレクティブに、以下のようにautoscroll属性をいれても、自動スクロールが効きません。
<div ng-include="temp" autoscroll></div>

autoscroll=""
のようにしても同様です。

ドキュメントを見ると、autoscroll属性の設定により、読み込んだ部分の位置までスクロールする、と書いてあるようなのですが。

どなたか、お分かりの方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

> autoscroll属性の設定により、読み込んだ部分の位置までスクロールする、と書いてあるようなのですが。

autoscroll属性は、ng-includeを指定した要素に自動スクロールする機能ではなく、
$anchorScrollのスクロール機能を使用するか否かを設定するものです

この$anchorScrollは、$location.hash()の値と一致するIDを持つ要素を探し、
存在した場合、その要素の位置までスクロールされます

http://jsfiddle.net/xsdauxn7/
上記にサンプルを作成しましたので参考にしてください

Comment: @hiroさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
autoscroll属性は、スクロール機能使用の可否を設定するものとのこと、理解致しました。

大変お手数ですが、もう1点、追加で質問させていただけますでしょうか。

公式サイトのデモ
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude
と同様に、動的にテンプレートを切り替える場合、
実行URLが「～.html#/scroll#scroll」であれば動作するのですが、
（初回起動時である）「～.html#/scroll」の場合、以下のようなエラーが発生してしまいます。作成いただいたサンプルでも、同様でした。
---
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop


10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
---

そこで、以下のようにしてみました。

$scope.$on('$includeContentRequested', function(e, path) {
  $location.hash('scroll');
});
 【つづく】

Comment: 【つづき】しかし、1回目のテンプレート読み込みでは、やはりオートスクロールが効かず、2回目の読み込みから（URLが「～.html#/scroll#scroll」で）効くようになります。
1回目のテンプレート読み込みで動作するようにしたいのですが、どのような設定を行えばよいでしょうか。
何度もすみませんが、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 調べた所デフォルトの状態ではlocationはHashbangモードで解析されるようです。（https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location）、そのため『～.html##scroll』のような指定にする必要があります。
本来なら$location.hash('scroll')時に、上記URLのように変換されるべきだと思いますが、バグなのかpath部分が無い場合hashをpathとして解析し『～.html#/scroll』のように変換され、hashとして機能していません。簡単な解決方法は、hashを指定する前に$location.path('');で空のpathを指定する。又は、hashPrefixに値を指定するとpathが無くても正しく解析されるようなのでhashPrefixに何か指定すると良いようです。angular.module('xx').config(function($locationProvider) {            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');  }]);

Comment: ご回答ありがとうござます。
お教えいただいた通り、空のpathを設定、または、hashPrefixを設定することにより、無事動作することを確認できました。大変助かります。重ねて、お礼申し上げます。